# Top combination of characteristics from table in R

Tags: r

Lets assume we have the following table with different categories from a data base.

```
id <- c('id1','id2','id3','id4','id5')
visit_number <- c(3, 8, 10, 7,8)
page_views<- c(35, 85, 102, 7,18)
channel <-c('Natural Search', 'Paid Search', 'Social Network', 'Paid Search', 'Social Network')
country <- c('ES','ES','NL','DE','DE')
device <- c('PC','PC','Other','PC','Other')
sex <- c('F','F','M','M','M')
age <- c('18-30','18-30','18-30','>50','<40')
product <-c('SRSX11W.MX', 'SRSX11W.MX', 'DSC-HX400V //SF-8C4', 'SLT-A58Y//Q E38', 'DSC-HX400V + LCS-U21 + SF-8C4')
producy_category <- c('audio','audio','camera','tablets','camera')
 price <- c(33.45, 82, 104.44, 72,88.45)
 # Join the variables to create a data frame
df <-data.frame(id,visit_number,page_views,channel,country,device,sex,age,product,producy_category,price)
df
```

I would like to calculate the top-performing combinations based on countries, channels, and product categories. The table is much bigger.
what kind of combinations should I do to predict this?

Comment: Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output.

Comment: It's hard for anyone to help you with the information you've given us. Please have a read of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and edit your question. Thanks.

Comment: thank you i edited the question with a reproducible sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` functions to create all combinations of `country`, `channel`, `producy_category` and calculate `sum` of `price`. We can `arrange` the output in descending order to get top-performing combinations.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  distinct(country, channel, producy_category) %>%
  do.call(crossing, .) %>%
  pmap_df(~ df %>% 
         filter(channel == ..1, country == ..2, producy_category == ..3) %>%
         group_by(channel, country, producy_category) %>%
         summarise(price = sum(price))) %>%
  arrange(desc(price)) -> result
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I have an error like : Error in Ops.factor(channel, ..1) : level sets of factors are different

Comment: @user3683485 It seems you are on R < 4.0.0. Turn your data to character or use `df <-data.frame(id,visit_number,page_views,channel,country,device,sex,age,product,producy_category,price, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: I still have the same error : Error in Ops.factor(clean_test.channel, ..1) : 
  level sets of factors are different when i am trying to do the same in the big table . `df<- data.frame(clean_test$country,clean_test$channel,clean_test$product_category,clean_test$price, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(df) <- c("country", "channel", "producy_category", "price")`

Comment: You did not convert the columns to characters. What does `sapply(df, class)` return? Try `df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: Ok the last one works i understand but the result is empty ! without  data available in table

Comment: Did you check `result` ? It atleast give few rows as output for the data you have shared. Does it work for you on that data?

Comment: Yes i checked it in my case the resut returns just headers even in the data i  shared. A tibble: 0 x 4
# Groups:   channel, country [0]
# ... with 4 variables: channel <chr>, country <chr>, producy_category <chr>, price <dbl>

Comment: That's weird because when I use the data that you have shared it gives me tibble with 5 rows and 4 columns.

Comment: Very weird. i run again and again the example but always 0 obs of 4 variables in the result ! of course the same for the big table ! but after conversion there is no error in the function that you propose.

Comment: What is your R version? Can you restart R and try again?

Comment: R version 3.6.2 . i did it restart and run again but still nothing. libraries work, functions as well but the result is 0.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is package version problem . My `packageVersion('tidyr')` is  `‘1.1.2’` and `packageVersion('dplyr')` is `‘1.0.1’`

Comment: In my case, the tidyr is the same but the dplyr is  ‘0.8.5’ and i am not able to update it. i suppose i have to update R ?

Comment: Yes, I think first you need to update R and then try updating other packages.

Comment: Is there any other way to do those calculations with another function or library?

Comment: There might be but I cannot test it if it works or not since my packages and R are all updated.

Comment: I don't understand how the packageVersion('dplyr') is responsible for an empty table  since the functions and inputs outputs are correct and work.

Comment: Ok after updating R and the packages i managed to run it for the example but not for the big table. If the big dataset is a df with 4 columns like country,    channel,producy_category, price this should work right ?

Comment: Thanks for the help i did some changes in the data set and it worked!